# Como faço para adicionar uma imagem a um programa python utilizando tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Estou tentando adicionar uma imagem a um programa com o seguinte código:

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()

imagem = PhotoImage(file="imagem")

lb = Label(root, imagem=imagem)

lb.place(x = 0, y = 20)

root.mainloop()
```

A imagem está salva na mesma pasta que o código do programa, mas mesmo assim não funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gabriel,

Na linha que você instância a `PhotoImage`, o nome da imagem precisa conter a extensão para que o programa encontre a mesma, se sua imagem for um jpg por exemplo, você coloca o nome com .jpg no final:

```
imagem = PhotoImage(file="imagem.jpg")
```

Além disso, quando você informa a imagem no `Label`, você passou `imagem=imagem`, porém está incorreto, o parâmetro correto do `Label` chama-se `image`, sem o M no final:

```
lb = Label(root, image=imagem)
```

Corrigindo esses pontos, seu programa ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()

imagem = PhotoImage(file="imagem.jpg")

lb = Label(root, image=imagem)

lb.place(x = 0, y = 20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Funcionou! Muito Obrigado!