# Como adicionar imagens em um programa gerado pelo PyInstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Estou criando um executável utilizando a linguagem de programação Python e sua biblioteca pyinstaller. Para criar a interface, estou usando a biblioteca TKinter.

Na interface do executável eu coloquei uma imagem utilizando um código similar a este: [Como faço para adicionar uma imagem a um programa python utilizando tkinter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/424781/como-fa%C3%A7o-para-adicionar-uma-imagem-a-um-programa-python-utilizando-tkinter) .

No entanto, esse código exige que o usuário tenha a imagem no seu PC. Como eu faço para que não seja preciso que o usuário tenha a imagem no seu PC? Ou seja, quero mandar para ele apenas o executável e a imagem ainda continuar sendo exibida. Seria possível?

Answer (score 5):

Tem 2 passos a seguir, primeiro adicionar o arquivo ao "empacotado", você pode fazer isso de duas maneiras:

### Usando os parametros `--add-data` e `--add-binary`

O `--add-data` deve ser usado para arquivos não binários, como arquivos de texto simples, exemplo:

```
pyinstaller --add-data=origem:destino foobar.py
```

Use o `pkg_resources.resource_filename`

```
pyinstaller --add-data=origem;destino foobar.py
```

Em Windows usasse o `;` em Linux e MacOS use o `:`, exemplo:

```
 pyinstaller --add-data="/home/example/foo.txt:." --add-data="/home/example/bar.txt:." example.py
```

Para separar a origem do destino. O `--add-data` pode ser usado múltiplas vezes, exemplo para adicionar dois arquivos em Windows:

```
 pyinstaller --add-data="C:\Users\new_g\Desktop\xyz\foo.txt;." --add-data="C:\Users\new_g\Desktop\xyz\bar.txt;." example.py
```

Note que depois do `;` usei o `.`, o ponto se refere ao caminho inicial do *"dentro"* do programa, se quiser adicionar o arquivo a uma subpasta, por exemplo chamando-a de `assets` você pode fazer algo como:

```
 pyinstaller --add-data="C:\Users\new_g\Desktop\xyz\foo.txt;assets" --add-data="C:\Users\new_g\Desktop\xyz\bar.txt;assets" example.py
```

Para adicionar arquivos binários use `--add-binary`, todo processo é igual ao anterior, só muda que deve usar para arquivos como imagens, vídeos, compactados (gz, zip, rar, 7z, etc), exemplo:

```
 pyinstaller --add-binary="C:\Users\new_g\Desktop\xyz\foo.jpg;assets" --add-binary="C:\Users\new_g\Desktop\xyz\bar.png;assets" example.py
```

> Nota: Se deseja adicionar tudo dentro de um único `.exe` use o
> parametro --onefile, exemplo:
>
> ```
> pyinstaller --onefile --add-binary="C:\Users\new_g\Desktop\xyz\foo.jpg;assets" --add-binary="C:\Users\new_g\Desktop\xyz\bar.png;assets" example.py
> ```

### Lendo o arquivo

Agora é a segunda etapa, isso é independente de estar usando Kivy, TKinter, ou simplesmente um script Python sem GUI (interface gráfica), para ler o arquivo deve-se usar a lib `pkg_resources.resource_filename`, em instalações Windows geralmente já vem instalado, mas se não tiver o `pkg_resources` execute o comando:

```
pip install setuptools
```

Após instalar no seu script você vai ler o arquivo assim (independente de executar `python exemple.py` ou executar de executar o `.exe` gerado, exemplo:

```
from pkg_resources import resource_filename

resource_1 = resource_filename(__name__, 'foo.txt')
resource_2 = resource_filename(__name__, 'bar.txt')

print('resource_1:', resource_1)
print('resource_2:', resource_2)
print(resource_1)
print(__name__)

with open(resource_1) as file:
    print(file.read())

print('----------')

with open(resource_2) as file:
    print(file.read())
```

Isso é um exemplo totalmente adaptável a qualquer lib, como Tkinter, pois o `pkg_resources.resource_filename()` retorna o caminho absoluto do arquivo.

### Leitura de uma imagem adicionada com `--add-binary` no Tkinter

No exemplo a seguir pode ler o arquivo `foo.png` e exibir em uma label

```
from pkg_resources import resource_filename
from tkinter import Tk, Label, PhotoImage


root = Tk()

resource_1 = resource_filename(__name__, 'foo.png')

photo = PhotoImage(file=resource_1)

message = Label(root, image=photo)
message.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo detalhamento na sua resposta. Ainda fiquei com uma dúvida: Mesmo seguindo esse procedimento, o executável só executa com sucesso se eu colocar as imagens dentro da pasta que ele está. É normal? Pensei que esse procedimento ia gerar um executável totalmente standalone, que não precisasse das imagens em mais nenhum local. Talvez eu esteja errando mesmo. Obrigado novamente!

Comment: @AugustoRodrigues não entendi, o exemplo que demonstrei não tem as imagens no mesmo local, eu peguei as imagens de outros locais, acho que você está confundindo as coisas, o que você quer na verdade é o parametro `pyinstaller --onefile ... example.py` (troque os ... pelos --add-binary), isso vai fazer criar um .exe sem os arquivos separados

Answer (score -4):

Você pode armazenar sua imagem em uma pasta "images", junta do executável/.py. Infelizmente não é possível utilizar uma imagem que não esteja armazenada no dispositivo...

Comment: Na verdade o usuário pode sim com PyInstaller empacotar um arquivo de dados manipulando o arquivo de especificações o [Spec File](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files) usando a opção [`--add-data`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-add-data) como argumento uma string contendo uma lista de tuplas onde o primeiro elemento é o caminho do arquivo e o segundo é diretório virtual. Acesse o arquivo em runtime com [`pkgutil.get_data()`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#using-data-files-from-a-module)

Comment: @AugustoVasques no caso de imagem seria `add-binary`, se eu não estiver enganado.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, sim você está correto. O equivoco é meu, a opção correta para empacotar uma imagem no executável é [`--add-binary`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-add-binary)